# Oracle SQL joining tables question from newbie

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm sure this question has been asked a lot (in many ways) but need help with extracting data from two tables matching certain data.
It is probably a simple answer but I'm just starting on SQL.

I have two tables:

**parts table** (p)

| code | code_desc | part_no | part |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | Fruits | 001 | Banana |
| 23 | Fruits | 002 | Apple |
| 24 | Veggies | 010 | Celery |
| 24 | Veggies | 010 | Onion |
| 25 | Misc | 125 | Sanitizer |

**codes table** (c)

| code | contract |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | Albany |
| 24 | Detroit |
| 25 | Chicago |

I simply want to display the code description, matching codes on each table.
e.g.,

| CD | contract | descrip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | Albany | Fruits |
| 23 | Albany | Fruits |
| 24 | Detroit | Veggies |
| 24 | Detroit | Veggies |
| 25 | Chicago | Sanitizer |

I have been tinkering with joins, left and right (literally), but seem to be getting ALL the rows returned from the first table.

| CD | contract | descrip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | Albany | Fruits |
| 24 | Detroit | Veggies |
| 25 | Chicago | Sanitizer |

this is one of the code examples I have, using inner join. I've tried left/right outer join as well, same results.

```
SELECT p.code, p.contract, c.code_desc 
FROM db1.parts p INNER JOIN db1.codes c ON p.code = c.code
```

also

```
SELECT p.code, p.contract, c.code_desc 
FROM db1.parts, db1.codes c where p.code = c.code
```

Thanks in advance and my apologies if this is so trivial ;)

Comment: Since you've stated Oracle I removed the `mysql` tag

Comment: It's not clear in your question which is your desired results - do you want all rows or distinct rows? If you want your last table then you need `select distinct`

Comment: please enter desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* since you state the query you have is returning *all rows from the first table* (why wouldn't it?) you just need to add `distinct` to your existing query - although the column aliases you've used do not align with the tables in your question.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.code, c.contract, p.code_desc 
FROM db1.parts p 
INNER JOIN db1.codes c ON p.code = c.code
```

Comment: distinct did it!